# a synopsis of @property/@synthesize syntax

Tags: objective-c, properties

I agree with the assessment that Apple's docs on `@property` and`@synthesize` are very good.  Also, I have read the excellent tutorials on stackoverflow.

I would like to ask someone to confirm or correct the following. Given the presence of:

```
@property UIWindow *itsWindow;      // .h file
@synthesize itsWindow = window_;    // .m file
```

and considering these statements:

1)  `self.itsWindow = nil;`
2)  `[self setItsWindow:nil];`
3)  `window_ = nil;`
4)  `itsWindow = nil;`

**(1)** is the message `[self itsWindow]`, whereas **(3)** and **(4)** are the actual class param.

If the above is correct, then any of the 4 statements would work in an `-init` class method.

Comment: [When a new object is created, all bits of memory (except for isa) —and hence the values for all its instance variables— are set to 0.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocAllocInit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH22-SW4) Therefore, you don't need to set your ivars to nil in your initializer.

Comment: Small thing: `-init` is an instance method, not a class method.

Answer (score 3):

(4) is incorrect. You can't access a property, even within an object, absent an object pointer. So you can say:

- `self.itsWindow`
- `[self itsWindow]`
- `self.itsWindow = nil`
- `aDifferentObject.itsWindow = nil`
- `[aDifferentObject setItsWindow:nil]`

but you can't just say `itsWindow = nil`.

Statements 1-3 are all okay, but you generally want to access ivars directly in init and dealloc methods, and use the property accessors everywhere else.

Comment: And just to add, statements 1 gets translated into statement 2, which executes code (because by default, properties are assigned) like statement 3.